# Stuck at What is the median UVa 10107

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, runtime-error, median

I am stuck at this uva problem i think my algorithm is right but the program crashes on running , I can't figure out where the problem is but i think it is with the iterator ??! Any help please !!!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, R, L;

    long long idx, aver;
    std::vector<long long> v;
    std::vector<long long>::iterator it;

    while(cin >> n)
    {
        it=v.begin();
        v.push_back(n);
        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

        if(v.size() == 1)
        {
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        }
        else if(v.size() % 2 == 0)
        {
            L=v.size() / 2 - 1;
            R=v.size() / 2;

            aver = (*(it + L) + *(it + R)) / 2;

            std::cout<< aver << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            idx = v.size() / 2;
            aver = *(it + idx);

            std::cout << aver << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Problem link](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=1048)

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/Tehxjw)

Comment: a) Use a debugger to find out where it crashes. b) Describe what your program should do, here.

Comment: @deviantfan c) Don't waste your time on silly online coding contests!

Comment: I am new at problem solving and i can't debug yet , thank you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Me? I'm not. But yes, I too think that "online judges" are nonsense.

Comment: @MazenMohamed You learn how to debug first. It's one of the most essential skills. Come back after for asking here.

Comment: @MazenMohamed Then now's the time to start: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Comment: @deviantfan I didn't meant you of course ;-) ...

Comment: @karel I can't understand what do you mean . Can you clarify a little bit ?

Comment: @deviantfan Thanks for help .

Comment: Your code compiled without errors and running it with only one integer as input gives the error message: `Segmentation fault (core dumped) Press ENTER to continue.` and pressing ENTER closes the console. You can fix the segmentation fault error by substituting `"hello"` for the string `*it` in line 21 of your code.

Comment: @karel I know that the code has no syntax errors but it is a runtime error where the process returns 255 <0xFF> error, after crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it I finally got accepted , the problem was with the iterator , it pointed to v.begin() when the vector was empty at the first iteration of the loop so the program crashed . I made the iterator to point to the beginning of the vector after doing the first push_back() , where the vector is not empty at this case.

Right Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,R,L;
    long long idx,aver;
    vector<long long>v;
    vector<long long>::iterator it;

    while(cin>>n)
    {

        v.push_back(n);
        it=v.begin();
        sort(v.begin(),v.end());



        if(v.size()==1){
            cout<<*it<<endl;
        }
        else if(v.size()%2==0)
        {
            L=v.size()/2-1;
            R=v.size()/2;

            aver=(*(it+L)+*(it+R))/2;

            cout<<aver<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            idx=v.size()/2;
            aver=*(it+idx);

            cout<<aver<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/WDpMdE)